# Does AT&T syntax work on intel platform?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, intel

I'm learning assembly.

I know that gcc supports at&t syntax but i want my program to run on intel processors.

So would it work on intel processors regardless the syntax or it must be intel syntax to work on intel platform!! i'm confused??

Thanks.

Comment: the CPU doesn't care for the assembler code (e.g. "ADD AX, 0x1234") , just for the machine code that's build of it (0x05, 0x34, 0x12)

Comment: To make matters worse, you probably confused `at&t` with `amd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

att vs intel syntax has been covered many times, here and other places.

Assembly language is a language defined by the assembler, the particular program used to convert the ASCII assembly language into machine code for the particular target you are interested in.  Unlike say a C or C++ compiler where there is a standard that defines the language, you can have 7 assemblers for the same target processor and there is no reason to assume that the assembly languages have to be compatible in any way shape or form.  It is the machine code the produce that matters and if that machine code matches the same target then use the tool you like the best for whatever reason.

For this case there was the intel format as defined by the intel documentation and supported by the intel assembler.  And then supported sorta by other assemblers.  The instructions were close or the same they might have had a compatibility mode and maybe they had their own directives.  For example as86 (or was it asm86 or a86?) tasm, masm, and currently nasm.  And then you had this AT&T syntax, someone somewhere (ATT?) decided to make an assembler with a goofy assembly language that specifically didnt match the intel documentation at all.  And that became the Intel vs AT&T syntax thing.   gnu assembler is well known for messing up existing assembly languages as well, and they apparently use AT&T with their own nuances thrown in.  they might have an intel syntax switch you should check.

The question you should be asking is the target, and assemblers like gnu assembler for x86 are often capable of generating code for various flavors of x86, so you need to make sure it matches your computer (most likely does if you dont add any target type/specific options).

There is no reason to assume an AT&T syntax assembler (gnu assembler (gas or as)) would not work.

Comment: err, GNU as *does* support both Intel & AT&T syntax.  see the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.26/as/i386_002dVariations.html).  not only that, but AT&T is the default.