# What is the relation between assembly-syntax and platform

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, cross-compiling

In this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=my39Gpt6bvY&t=4m38s) the guy explains that there are 2 types of assembly syntax - Intel and AT&T. Is there a relation between assembly-syntax and platform, (for example intel platforms assemblers only accept Intel assembly syntax)?

Comment: No. There are two *syntaxes* for Intel x86 assembly language: Intel syntax and AT&T syntax. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax).

Comment: @CodyGray Wow thanks. Should I delete this question or post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Um, either one. I was looking for a duplicate, because I would have sworn this would have been one, but I didn't really come up with a good match. [This is the best I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906734/does-att-syntax-work-on-intel-platform). Close, and probably answers it, but not an *exact* duplicate. We do have this information covered in the [[tag:x86]] tag wiki, and probably also the [[tag:att]] and [[tag:intel-syntax]] tag wikis, but nobody ever looks there. :-)

Comment: AT&T was using an (intel) x86 at the time.  Creating a toolchain for their system they chose the assembly syntax.

Comment: Note that there are different variations on Intel syntax.  NASM and MASM syntax are both Intel-style syntaxes, but they are *not* compatible.  `mov eax, OFFSET  my_global` in MASM/TASM = `mov eax my_global` in NASM/YASM.  In MASM/TASM syntax, `mov eax, my_global` = `mov eax, [my_global]` (It accepts both, but in NASM only the latter is a load.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No connection whatsoever.  An assembly language syntax is defined by the assembler, the program that parses it.  The machine code is the only real standard that has to be conformed to.  Although folks like to talk about two x86 syntaxes for example there are many many more than that as the syntax encompasses all of the text not just the ordering of operands.  There are multiple syntaxes for ARM, and others for the same reason.

It is in the interest of the chip or ip vendor to define the instruction set and at the same time in their interest to present this with an assembly language syntax, or at least with respect to the instructions (there is a lot more to an assembly language than just the instructions, in the case of x86 variation within the instructions themselves other than just the ordering of operands), and these vendors make or have made for them at a minimum an assembler and linker as needed (in their best interest).  Their documentation and this specific assembler ideally match (in their best interest).  But the standardization stops there, the next person/team to make an assembler only needs to conform to the machine code, and will often make at least subtle changes making the code incompatible (intentionally or not, why bother making a perfect clone).  For whatever reason gas implementations tend to create an incompatible language from the chip/ip vendor except for the cases where the gas version IS the vendor driven initial version (lets say risc-v for example)

The syntax connection and binary file format (elf, coff, etc) are important with respect to the toolchain.  For obvious reasons compilers output assembly language then launch the assembler, so the code produced by the compiler needs to match the syntax of the assembler in that chain.  Likewise the object file format output by the assembler needs to match that of the linker, I assume that linkers like gnu ld dont actually rely on the assembler for patching up the machine code used during linking, just modifies the machine code directly (or adds machine code as needed although in that case maybe does use assembly language, have not personally inspected/tested/confirmed).

One can argue since the assembler comes before the compiler that the compiler conforms to the assembler, if it is the same folks then possible that items are added to the assembler to help the overall toolchain solution, but would expect the assembler and thus the assembly language as a whole comes first.

And lastly we as programmers expect the installed compiler to produce programs for that system/platform.  gcc on a linux machine makes working programs gcc hello.c -o hello.  Without us having to do the bootstrap and linking for that platform, and that comes from the C library usually, but depends on the design of the toolchain, everyone from start to end may have to be system aware.

Comment: so there may be a connection in that say you are on linux and you are relying on gnu and gas for that target uses a syntax by default, then you loosely have a connection.  But to some extent that is your choice by using that toolchain on that system/target.

Answer (score 0):

I answer in case someone else made that mistake. As Cody Gray commented, both the Intel and AT&T are in-fact Intel X86 assembly languages.

Resources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/att
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-syntax

Comment: The [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has lots of resources, like http://agner.org/optimize/ as well as links to assembler manuals.  In an answer, you can write `[tag:intel-syntax]` to get a tag block with the mouseover dropdown for questions / info (the tag wiki) / ...